# Existing widgets not available in a widget template in some (strange) cases

Tags: dojo, js-amd

This took me a while. A long while. I battled two problems at once (circular dependencies, fixed with refactoring, and *this* problem). To get this problem into a JSFiddle required a LOT of work... but I think it was worth it.
So:

http://jsfiddle.net/EVbTL/3/

I define three widgets:

- r.AppMainScreen -- This is the main app's widget. Easy: just a bunch of tabs, and a button which contains a simple button, which goes:

  ```
  // SUbmit form
  this.form.onSubmit = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("HERE");
      dialog = new r.RetypePasswordDialog();
      dialog.show();           
      return false;
  }
  ```

Pretty uninteresting.

- r.RetypePasswordDialog() -- A templated widget which represents a dialog box. The only interesting thing about it is:

  `< input name="password" id="${id}_password" data-dojo-attach-point="password" data-dojo-type="app.ValidationPassword" />`

It's a simple custom widget, defined in this very file, which does validation. NOTE: I know there is no point in having a subclass here for this little work. Please keep in mind that this is an *example*.

- r.ValidationPassword()

An augmented ValidationTextBox with some extra validation.

If you click on the button, you get:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not load class 'app.ValidationPassword
```

...?!? app.ValidationPassword has *definitely* been defined. It ought to be available there. At the beginning, I thought it was because of aa circular dependency (it was very fun, yesterday: I had to learn about AMD circular dependencies WHILE trying to figure out this problem...)

If you uncomment this line, executed within the script:

```
TEST = new r.RetypePasswordDialog();
```

The whole thing works. It's a meaningless instance, and I cannot figure out why on earth this would or should make a difference.

Explanations most welcome... I couldn't find any!

Thank you,

Merc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app = new r.AppMainScreen( {});
```

You redefine the global `app` variable here, but are trying to use it elsewhere as the base object for your type system. Use `var` to scope variables to the function.

Comment: Oh my, oh my, oh my. Oh goodness. Well, thank you. I really want to swear now. I wasted hours of my life of something so idiotic. Circular dependencies, plus calling something "app" without "var" in front of the variables name, created the perfect storm on my code. No wonder I had trouble reproducing it. Thank you.